# Eclipse Scout call getDataByKey too many times

Tags: drop-down-menu, eclipse-scout

I have form with Table. This table has some smart fields.

My problem is that when I fill data in table (by initialization) all smart fields call getDataByKey with id (what it right) but it is not called once what I would expect but 30 times.

I dig a little bit for answer and I discovered that function is called so many times, because inside class `AbstractTable` inside `processDecorationBuffer` the table with all calls `m_cellLookupBuffer` has a lot of calls stored inside (512 insted 9).

Has anyone the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a SmartColumn in a table, scout needs to do the Lookup "key -> text" for each row. As you mentioned, in some cases it can be expensive. This is why there is an additional concept: BatchLookupCall / BatchLookupService.

The idea is to first collect all the rows and the required LookupCall and to process them in one batch.

To answer your question, I had to set up a small playground project. Here the key points I have noticed:

### Type of your key

Batch LookupCall check the equals method of your call which relies on the equality of the key Object. If you are using a custom Type as key, ensure `equals()` and `hashCode()` is properly implemented.

### Way of adding rows in the table

If you add the rows one after the other, like this:

```
Table table = getMyTableField().getTable();
ITableRow r;

r = table.addRow(table.createRow());
table.getTextColumn().setValue(r, "Lorem");
table.getMyColumn().setValue(r, 1L);

r = table.addRow(table.createRow());
table.getTextColumn().setValue(r, "Ipsum");
table.getMyColumn().setValue(r, 3L);

r = table.addRow(table.createRow());
table.getTextColumn().setValue(r, "Dolor");
table.getMyColumn().setValue(r, 1L);

r = table.addRow(table.createRow());
table.getTextColumn().setValue(r, "Figus");
table.getMyColumn().setValue(r, 4L);
```

Scout computes the table content too often… I could observe too many calls to the lookup service. I think there is some optimization possibility in this domain.

This does not happen if you import all your rows in one step, for example using the [TableData](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/TableData) included in the FormData or in the TablePageData.